# Meteor Collection ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am following along with the Discover Meteor book and began learning about Collections. I am running Meteor 1.4.

In my **app/lib/collections/posts.js** I have the following code:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
```

I then proceeded to query Mongo with the following:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.posts.insert({title: "A new post"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
meteor:PRIMARY> db.posts.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("579fd616f0672da283091b1a"), "title" : "A new post" }
```

As explained, I am supposed to go to my browser console and examine the objects.

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Is this issue related to the content in the book being on an older version of Meteor or am I blatantly missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that these features were once built into Meteor. While running Meteor 1.4 I had to install the [Meteor Toys](https://github.com/MeteorToys/allthings) package and can successfully follow along with the instructed commands.

Answer (score 0):

If your autopublish and insecure packages are removed, you should subscribe for certain range of data, so you can use it on client.

```
In server:
if(Meteor.isServer){
   Meteor.publish('Posts',function(){
      return Posts.find();
   }
}
```

In Client

```
Meteor.subscribe('Posts');
```

> It's a good idea to put models in your AppName/models, cuz they should
>   be loaded parallel in server and client

I hope that would be helpful, Cheers